# Email verification in android app

Tags: android

I am developing an email verification i.e. user enter his/her email, app send a message to user email with some random code.
This is kind of OTP system where user has to provide this OTP to verify screen.

My problem is I am not receiving email.
I am using below code in the register.java

```
 private void sendEmail(String mail,String val)
{
    Log.d("mail:",mail);
    Log.d("val",val);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{mail});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Welcome user");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Please enter the code "+val+" to verify your account");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



}
```

I checked the mail and val value in Log.d is showing valid values, but I am not receiving email on my gmail.(i am using my own id for testing).
Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Are you getting an activity chooser?

Comment: Generally you should send user's email to server, and server should send the email. And when the users enters that OTP in the app, the app should check the code with the server.

Comment: I am trying to generate a 4 digit number and passing it to my verify screen. where user can enter his 4 digit number received in email to verify.

Comment: @crashOveride I am not getting chooser.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mehrdad said you should use a server.

But if you still want to send email from your app follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/1021695)

The problem with this way is that you need to put your email and password in your app.